# How do I change my list item style with a foundation icon?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I've downloaded a set of foundation icons but I'm having a hard time finding documentation on how to use this icons in my css code.

I know I can use it in my markup as so:

```
<i class="fi-check"></i>
```

but I want to include it in my css file

```
@import url("foundation-icons/foundation-icons.css");
```

and start using them here.  for example I want to change all the list item styles to be checkmarks.  Basically what I want is:

```
.myClass li { list-style: fi-check; }
```

Is it possible to do this somehow?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easiest to use them in your markup as you've pointed out.

```
<i class="fi-check"></i>
```

However if you want to recreate this for your own custom style you'd have to recreate/change the css rules found in `foundation-icons.css`

First you'd need to pull in the `@font-face`:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "foundation-icons";
  src: url("foundation-icons.eot");
  src: url("foundation-icons.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
       url("foundation-icons.woff") format("woff"),
       url("foundation-icons.ttf") format("truetype"),
       url("foundation-icons.svg#fontcustom") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Then you'll need to add it to your custom css like so:

```
.myClass li:before {
  font-family: "foundation-icons";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: inherit;

  content: "\f126";
}
```

The last line references the `check` icon in the `foundation-icons` file. So, if you wanted to change the icon to something else you'd need to look through `foundation-icons.css` to see what code to put into the `content` section.

For example:

```
trash = content: "\f204";
stop = content: "\f1ef";
```

Hope this makes sense!